# How to use IF to display a value based on values in other columns

Tags: google-sheets

Given the following problem:

```
Col1      Col2      Col3      Col4
Values    Values    Values    Outcome
```

There are 4 possible values for Col1 - Col3 i.e. "Normal", "Mild", "Moderate", "Severe' 
with 3 possible outcomes i.e. "Normal", "Intervention", "Refer"

I would like to display a result based on the following conditions:

1. If **any** of the values in Col1 - Col3 is "Mild" **OR** "Moderate", the outcome is "intervention"
2. If **any** of the values in Col1 - Col3 is "Severe", the outcome is "refer"
3. If there are different values in Col1 - Col3, "Refer" will always be chosen over "intervention"
4. If **all** values are normal, then the outcome is "normal"

I have tried the `IFS` but couldn't figure out the argument for values in different columns. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically you are asking for this:

```
=IF(OR(A1="Severe",   B1="Severe",   C1="Severe"),   "Refer",
 IF(OR(A1="Mild",     B1="Mild",     C1="Mild"),     "Intervention",
 IF(OR(A1="Moderate", B1="Moderate", C1="Moderate"), "Intervention",
 IF(AND(A1="Normal",  B1="Normal",   C1="Normal"),   "Normal", ))))
```

Comment: I tried the solution, however when one of the value is "severe" in col1 and "moderate" in col2, the outcome still displays as "intervention". How do I make sure that in any given condition, the more severe condition is always given priority? -question edited-

Comment: by moving it on the first row... answer edited. try now

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=ArrayFormula(IFS(COUNTIF(lEFT(A1:C1),"S")>0,"Refer",countif(left(A1:C1),"N")=3,"Normal",1,"Intervention"))
```